# If my B1/B2 visa expires can I apply for an ESTA instead?

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas

I hold a B1/B2 visa that expires in July 2024.
If I do not renew it can I apply/travel under an ESTA instead?
I may only travel to the USA once more - so would rather use an ESTA as opposed to renewing my visa.
Thanks

Comment: What is your citizenship, and most importantly, what was the reason you applied for a visa if you were eligible for ESTA?

Comment: British - many many years ago I was planning to live in the USA as was told (incorrectly by a third party) that as I had a very old motoring conviction that I would need to have a visa to travel. This turned out not to be the case, I would have been eligible for visa waiver. Even the embassy in London were surprised I'd applied for a visa, but because I'd already applied it was issued anyway. Now I want to let it lapse and travel on an ESTA - but I don;t want to turn up in the USA and be turned away.

Answer (score 1):

> If I do not renew it can I apply/travel under an ESTA instead?

If you are eligible for ESTA, there is nothing that would prevent you from apply for it even if you've previously held a visa